How to run a java application on AWS ec2 instance
I made a simple Hello World java app, and I'm trying to run it amazon web serves AWS by making a virtual machine and launching a ec2 instance.
This is my java program HelloWorld.java
package demo;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World and welcome!");

    }
}

I've installed java.
[ec2-user@ip-###-##-##-## ~]$ java -version
openjdk version "22" 2024-03-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-22.0.0.37.1 (build 22+37-FR)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-22.0.0.37.1 (build 22+37-FR, mixed mode, sharing)

I made sure that I have a javac version
[root@ip-###-##-##-## ec2-user]# javac -version
javac 22

But if I try to run it, I get
[root@ip-172-31-20-12 ec2-user]# javac HelloWorld.java
error: file not found: HelloWorld.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options

Been at this for some time but I don't know why it can't find my file.

The error is clear. Perhaps you out the file in a different directory or named it something else?

Note that javac HelloWorld.java does not run your Java application. It compiles the source code to bytecode. You then need to run your application with java.

There may be few reasons for this error.

Make sure that your are compiling your java file using javac command in the correct directory where HelloWorld.java file is located. If this java file is in different location, you need to navigate that directory using cd command. Then you can compile your code by using javac HelloWorld.java

Check the file permission using ls -l command to ensure the file has relevant permission

Check the user permission for that file. It means verify the user tries to run this java file has sufficient permission to access the file


